# How to pass filepath and parameters to shell.shellExecute command

Tags: c#

how to pass file path and parameters to `shell.shellExecute` command. 
For example I am trying following

`:shell.ShellExecute("L:\\test\\test.exe",["/abc /pqr /xyz"]);`

Here, `abc`,`pqr`,`xyz` are the parameters required to open the file `test.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below command where you can send the required arguments using

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments
```

Below is the Sample code .

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...

Process process = new Process();

// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "process.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-n";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using shell you can use process to call your exe with parameter. Below is the sample code

```
private static void RunExeWithParameter(string exePath, string parameter1, string parameter2)
{
    string error = "";
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + exePath + "\"";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + parameter1 + " \"" + parameter2 + "\"";
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.Close();
    }
    if (error.Trim().Trim("\r\n".ToCharArray()).Trim() != "")
    {
        throw new Exception(error);
    }
}
```